# I have an error trying to open Atom from WSL, up until yesterday it worked perfectly

Tags: ubuntu, cmd, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using Atom for some time now and I find very nice the ability to open it from the WSL command line with `atom .`.

The problem is today after starting the PC when I type this command the command window returns this error:

```
net.js:200
this._handle.open(options.fd);
             ^

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (net.js:200:18)
    at createWritableStdioStream (internal/process/stdio.js:164:16)
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (internal/process/stdio.js:14:14)
    at console.js:246:38
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:596:7)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:541:18)
    at setupGlobalConsole (bootstrap_node.js:310:41)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:70:7)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Any idea on how to solve it?
The usual commands like `git add .`, `git commit`, etc. are working fine.

PS: I type these commands in Ubuntu 18.04 that I have downloaded from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 3):

I also just recently ran into this issue, not sure what is causing it but a workaround that fixed my problem is to make an alias that directly calls the `atom.exe` file.

Open your `bashrc` file with `vim ~/.bashrc` and enter:

`alias atom='/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.31.1/atom.exe'`

Then save and exit. Im using version 1.31.1 of atom, but you would swap that out to whatever version of atom you're using. After that, just run `source ~/.bashrc` and you should be able to use atom like usual.

Comment: This worked for me. Just missing a small `'` at the end